# java netbeans 6.5.3 shows cannot find symbol getText

Tags: java, compiler-errors, netbeans6.5

Hey guys I can't understand why I am getting this error of cant find symbol getText.
[These are my classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs5X5.png)

[This is the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqeCy.png)

Comment: You probably want to call the function.

Comment: bcz, if you are attempting to call a function you need to show what (if any) parameters you are passing using parenthesises... try this instead `a.getText()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have forgotten the `()` in the end of method called.

Try `testField.getText()` or `testField.getText().toString()`.